# Loop through tables and delete data

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-2013

I have the following code that generates an error.

I want to loop through all the tables on the active worksheet and delete the data except for the data on two specified in the code.

```
Sub Clear_Tables()

Dim tbl As ListObject

For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

    If tbl <> "Table_Extracted_Data_Summary" Or tbl <> "Manual_Entries" Then
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    Else

    End If

Next tbl

End Sub
```

The error code is:

**Run-time error '91':**

**Object variable or With block variable not set**

I have got the following code working but for some reason if deletes the contents of the 2 tables i want to leave

```
Sub Clear_Tables()

'PURPOSE: Loop through and apply a change to all Tables in the Active Excel 
Sheet

Dim TableToCheck As ListObject

For Each TableToCheck In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    If TableToCheck.Name = "Table_Extracted_Data_Summary" Or 
TableToCheck.Name = "Manual_Entries" Then 'Name of Table you do NOT want to 
update
        If Not (TableToCheck.DataBodyRange Is Nothing) Then 
TableToCheck.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    End If
Next TableToCheck

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps,  tbl.Name

Comment: @donPablo this didnt work im afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend your second code to the following. You want tables whose name is NOT A and is NOT B.

```
Sub Clear_Tables()

    'PURPOSE: Loop through and apply a change to all Tables in the Active Excel
    Sheet

    Dim TableToCheck As ListObject

    For Each TableToCheck In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        If TableToCheck.Name <> "Table_Extracted_Data_Summary" And _
            TableToCheck.Name <> "Manual_Entries" Then 'Name of Table you do NOT want to update

            If Not (TableToCheck.DataBodyRange Is Nothing) Then
                TableToCheck.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next TableToCheck

End Sub
```

Or revert from `ClearContents` to `Rows.Delete` if appropriate.

Comment: This gives me a compile error: **Next without For**

Comment: @PeterMogford Did you discover why..? I have edited the answer, it is the previous End If that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the AND operator (an OR might require parentheses):

```
Sub Clear_Tables()

Dim tbl As ListObject

For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

    If tbl <> "Table_Extracted_Data_Summary" And tbl <> "Manual_Entries" Then
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    End If

Next tbl

End Sub
```

Otherwise your syntaxt seems fine.
I was unable to reproduce your error "91".